# Javascript object inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Please help me in understanding this piece of code.

```
var person = {
    'first-name': 'FirstName',
    'last-name': 'LastName',
    'gender': 'Male'
};

var anotherPerson = new Object(person);
anotherPerson.desig = 'Designation';

console.log('Another person designation: ' + anotherPerson['desig'] + ', person designation: ' + person['desig']);
```

I expected the output to be `Another person designation: Designation, person designation: undefined` but to my surprise I found it to be `` `Another person designation: Designation, person designation: Designation ``.

According to me `anotherPerson` is extending `person` object and properties set to `anotherPerson` should not be visible to `person` object. Am I wrong here? Or is that both the object are pointing to the same location?

**[EDIT]**

Now there are even more surprises.

I added the following code to the above.

```
person.place = 'XYZ';
console.log(person['place'] + ', ' + anotherPerson['place']); // Expected: XYZ, undefined. Result: XYZ, XYZ.
```

Based on the above result and answers I thought that both objects are referring to the same location. Now I added few more lines

```
person = undefined;
console.log(anotherPerson['place']) //Expected: error, Result: XYZ. ??!?!?
console.log(person['place']) // Expected: error, Result: error.
```

Can someone throw some light on me to understand this?
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: There's no inheritance here. Just two references to the same object.

Comment: Then how can you clone the object and make a new one? I, like the OP probably, assumed that new would make a NEW object.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Object.create() is the correct way http://ncombo.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/javascript-inheritance-done-right/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing extending or any kind of inheritance.

This comes closer:

```
var Person = function () {
    this["first-name"] = 'FirstName',
    this["last-name"] = 'LastName',
    this["gender"] = 'Male'
};

var person = new Person();
var anotherPerson = new Person();
```

Now you have two *seperate* instances of `Person`. If you also want `anotherPerson` to be a subclass ..

```
var Person = function () {
    this["first-name"] = 'FirstName',
    this["last-name"] = 'LastName',
    this["gender"] = 'Male'
};

var AnotherPerson = function () {
    this.desig = "Designation";
}
AnotherPerson.prototype = new Person();   // inherit from Person
AnotherPerson.prototype.constructor = AnotherPerson;  // reset constructor

var person = new Person();
var anotherPerson = new AnotherPerson();

console.log(person.desig); // undefined
console.log(anotherPerson.desig); // Designation
```

Comment: I had just finished writing up the same first block of code ;) +1

Comment: @Frits Thanks for your reply. I get the code you have explained. So when we do `new Object(person)` is it that `anotherPerson` is referring to the same location? I tried adding a new property to `person` and `anotherPerson` was able to read that new property successfully. Why is it so?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `new Object(person)` does .. maybe it just resolves to `person`? I do know that it doesn't magically extend from `person` :P

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Hmm very weird. I some times doubts whether I really know javascript when these kind of results are shown

Comment: I don't like the way native prototypes work in JavaScript, supposedly it has a memory leak too! Find a framework to do inheritance for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but for me, this is how I clone an object in such a way that I can extend it:

```
var anotherPerson = new Object();
for(i in person) anotherPerson[i]=person[i];
```

Instead of

```
var anotherPerson = new Object(person);
```

It then works as expected.

Comment: May I know what exactly happens when we do `var anotherPerson = new Object(person)`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` function (note: the same, even more startlingly if you're not familiar with what's going on, applies to calling `new Object(...)`) doesn't create a new object if it's passed something that isn't of boolean, number or string type; it just returns the already existing object. (Rationale: because it's already an Object. Almost everything is an Object in Javascript.)

Therefore, `anotherPerson` is the exact same object as `person`, so when you modify it you modify `person` too.

I do not claim that this is sensible behaviour; but it is what the language spec defines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend/inherit an object then you can do

```
var person = {
    'first-name': 'FirstName',
    'last-name': 'LastName',
    'gender': 'Male'
};
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function')
{
    Object.create=function(o)
    {
        function F(){}
        F.prototype=o;
        return new F();
    }
}
var newPerson=Object.create(person);
newPerson.age=25;
newPerson.gender="Female";

console.log(person.gender); // Male
console.log(newPerson.gender); // Female

console.log(person.age); // undefined
console.log(newPerson.age); // 25
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qKyCL/)

**Reference:** [**Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript**](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)

Comment: The Douglas Crockford way! Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

a general solution for inheritance implementation in JavaScript

```
function inherits(base, extension)
{
   for ( var property in base )
   {
      try
      {
         extension[property] = base[property];
      }
      catch( warning ){}
   }
}
```